# magento 2 setup freezes browser

Tags: magento2, error, installation, setup

I am quite new to magento so I was wondering if I did something wrong or forgot to do something.

I am trying to install magento 2.0.2 on my local machine (vagrant homestead) with the following configuration

- PHP 5.6.18
- MySQL 5.6.28
- Nginx 1.8.0

All the required php modules are installed and activated.

The issue that I am having is that if I enter the setup url in the browser then the browser freezes and after some time the browser ask if I want to kill the website or wait. Opening the element inspector I notice a few errors in the console.

Here's the screenshot with the frozen browser

[image: frozen browser]

And here's the error message

[image: error message]
The php.ini file had been updated accordingly to the magento recommandations. I also did chmod 777 on files and folders inside the magento root folder (only on my local machine for debugging purpose).

The owner of the files is also the web user.

Does anyone know why the setup would freeze? Thanks a lot for the help!

**UPDATE:**
I was installing magento via compose using these instructions: devdocs[DOT]magento[DOT]com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html

Also it was possible to install magento 2 via command line. But as it seems the pub folder was missing files (css, js, img, ...)

Comment: can you clean all data related to your host?  Could be related to this github issue. Please follow instructions posted here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2891#issuecomment-173349882

Comment: @Maddy: thanks for your help. But the issue was the ownership of the file system. I posted below my own answer. But thanks anyway for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the issue. It was because of the ownership. Magento 2 need the magento_user to be owner of the file system (as described in the documentation).

Lesson learned, you have to read all words/sentences of the manual/documentation!

Here's the piece of text that I was missing:

> The important things:
>
> The owner of the Magento file system:
>
> - Must have full control (read/write/execute) of all files and
>     directories.
> - Must not be the web server user; it should be a
>     different user.

(http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html)

Comment: How did you fix this on homestead?

Comment: @ChrisMorris: it seems as the documentation has changed a bit. I added the magento_user to the same group as the apache user so it has full control of all files and directories. As it seems the default user to execute the some magento files is the magento_user. So you need to switch to magento_user in order to install magento 2. (I am not sure anymore of the details but this should be how it was when I installed magento 2)

Comment: @ChrisMorris: here at the last section [File system permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/compman-checklist.html) you can find some more official documentation